# Loop multiple variables using group_by to get multiple outcomes

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

For the data described below, I am trying to summarize the values using group by function based on two variables, MUNICIPIO and a dynamic variable which is being looped.

```
df <- data.frame(
  department = c(rep("5", 18)),
  municipio = c(rep("501", 6), rep("502", 6), rep("503", 6)),
  area = c(rep("1", 9), rep("2", 9) ),
  pcp6 = c(rep("1", 10), rep("2", 8) ),
  pcp9 = c(rep("1", 3), rep("2", 1), rep("9", 2 ), rep("1", 1), rep("2", 3), rep("9", 2 ), 
           rep("1", 2), rep("2", 1), rep("9", 3 ))
)
```

I am using the code below to get the result however each dynamic variable has a different unique summary count:

```
vars <- colnames(df)
vars <- vars[-which(vars == "department")]

Outlier_check <- vector("list", length(vars))

for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
    Outlier_check[[i]] <- df %>%
    group_by(municipio, vars[[i]]) %>%
    summarise(length(which(!is.na(vars[[i]]))))
}
```

The result I am looking for is below, however, it is for a range of municipio from 501 - 512 :

| municipio | pcp9 | length(pcp9) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 501 | 1 | 3 |
| 501 | 2 | 1 |
| 501 | 9 | 2 |
| 502 | 1 | 1 |
| 502 | 2 | 3 |
| 502 | 9 | 2 |
| 503 | 1 | 2 |
| 503 | 2 | 1 |
| 503 | 9 | 3 |

| municipio | pcp6 | length(pcp6) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 501 | 1 | 6 |
| 502 | 1 | 4 |
| 502 | 2 | 2 |
| 503 | 2 | 6 |

I have two issues:

1. How to get the loop variables to process through and calculated the required summary?
2. How to save different sets of summary structures to extract in possibly one data structure?

There are about 7,77,000 rows in the original data.

I have gone through quite a few references on Stack Overflow but haven't been able to get a solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your solution:

1. You are using a character vector to call a column. In the `tidyverse`, you should simply call the object by its name without quotation marks. This is called `tidyeval`. You can also use `!!sym` -- this converts your character vector into a column name, or symbol, and then gets the column with the `!!`.
2. You are attempting to group by `municipio` twice in one case. You need to remove it from your list of column names before iterating through.
3. Instead of the complicated `summarise` statement, we can simply use `dplyr::count` to group the items and count the number of occurrences.

Here is the code that will work:

```
library(dplyr)

vars <- colnames(df)
vars <- vars[-which(vars %in% c("department", "municipio")]

Outlier_check <- vector("list", length(vars))

for (i in seq_along(vars)) {
  Outlier_check[[i]] <- df %>%
    count(municipio, !!sym(vars[[i]]))
}
```

The output is:

```
Outlier_check
#> [[1]]
#>   municipio area n
#> 1       501    1 6
#> 2       502    1 3
#> 3       502    2 3
#> 4       503    2 6
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   municipio pcp6 n
#> 1       501    1 6
#> 2       502    1 4
#> 3       502    2 2
#> 4       503    2 6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   municipio pcp9 n
#> 1       501    1 3
#> 2       501    2 1
#> 3       501    9 2
#> 4       502    1 1
#> 5       502    2 3
#> 6       502    9 2
#> 7       503    1 2
#> 8       503    2 1
#> 9       503    9 3
```

Comment: You might replace `group_by...` - `summarize(n = n())` here with `count(municipio, !!sym(vars[[i]]))`

Comment: Great suggestion - I edited my response to reflect this change

Comment: You could also use `vars <- vars[-which(vars %in% c("department", "municipio"))]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments and corrections! Really helpful to understand where I messed up.